# Getting stuck doing a complicated SQL query for patent research purposes

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to gather data for a research study for my university thesis. Unfortunately I am not a computer science or programming expert and do not have any SQL experience.

For my thesis I need to do a SQL query answering the question: "Give me all patents of a company X where there is more than one applicant (other company) in a specific time span". The data I want to extract is stored on a database called PATSTAT (where I have a 1 month trial) and is using - dont be surprised SQL.

I tried a lot of queries but all the time I am getting different syntax errors.

This is how the interface looks like:
http://www10.pic-upload.de/07.07.13/7u5bqf7jsow.png

I think I have a really good understanding of what (also from an SQL POV) needs to be done but I cannot execute it.

My idea: As result I want the names of the companies (with reference to the company entered below)

```
SELECT person_name from tls206_person table
```

Now because I need a criteria like

```
WHERE nb_applicants > 1 from tls201_appln table
```

I need to join these two tables tls206 and tls201. I did read some brief introduction guide on SQL (provided by european patent office) and because both tables have no common "reference key" we need to use the table tls207_pers_appln als "intermediate" so to speak. Now thats the point where I am getting stuck. I tried the following but this is not working

```
SELECT person_name, tls201_appln.nb_applicants 
FROM tls206_person
INNER JOIN tls207_pers_appln ON tls206_person.person_id= tls207_pers_appln.person_id 
INNER JOIN tls207_pers_appln ON tls201_appln.appln_id=tls201_appln.appln_id
WHERE person_name = "%Samsung%" 
AND tls201_appln.nb_applicants > 1
AND tls201_appln.ipr_type = "PI"
```

I get the following error: "0:37:11 [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0 secs] [Error Code: 1064, SQL State: 0] Not unique table/alias: 'tls207_pers_appln'"

I think for just 4 Hours SQL my approach is not to bad but I really need some guidance on how to proceed because I am not making any progress.

Ideally I would like to count (for every company) and for every row respectively how many "nb_applicants" were found.

If you need further information for giving me guidance, just let me know.

Looking forward to your answers.

Best regards
Kendels

Comment: You say 'more than one applicant (other company) in a specific time span' but what does that mean? More than one applicant for *what*?

Comment: For a Patent Invention. PI.

Comment: For the *same* `patent invention`, the `same patent invention group` or just *any* `patent invention`. If the latter, it seems like that's going to be a very large result set!?!

Comment: Sry if I am unclear: I will give you an example. If for a specific patent invention more than 1 company is the applicant (so they did this patent invention jointly - for example because they have a research cooperation) I want a list of exactly that patent invention for example for the company Samsung. I will delimit this to a time span from 2005-2011.

Comment: An result I would like to see for this question: Give me all joint patents where Samsung is involved would be: Samsung, Company2, Company3 (as one column) and then another column with the number of companies involved in this specific patent invention (3 for e.g.). I am not really interested in what kind of inventions or sth. like that

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the table `tls201_appln`, but it is not in the `from` clause.  I am guessing that the second reference to `tls207_pers_appln` should be to the other table:

```
SELECT person_name, tls201_appln.nb_applicants 
FROM tls206_person
INNER JOIN tls207_pers_appln ON tls206_person.person_id = tls207_pers_appln.person_id 
INNER JOIN tls201_appln ON tls201_appln.appln_id = tls207_pers_appln.appln_id
WHERE person_name like '%Samsung%"'
AND tls201_appln.nb_applicants > 1
AND tls201_appln.ipr_type = "PI"
```

Comment: This looks right to me, but I suspect you should also be using a `LIKE` query for the person_name: `WHERE person_name LIKE "%Samsung%"`

Answer (score 0):

another way of doing the same thing, which you might find easier to understand (if you are new to sql it is impressive you have got so far), is:

```
SELECT tls206_person.person_name, tls201_appln.nb_applicants 
  FROM tls206_person, tls207_pers_appln, tls201_appln
 WHERE tls206_person.person_id = tls207_pers_appln.person_id 
   AND tls201_appln.appln_id = tls201_appln.appln_id
   AND tls206_person.person_name LIKE "%Samsung%" 
   AND tls201_appln.nb_applicants > 1
   AND tls201_appln.ipr_type = "PI"
```

(it's equivalent to the other answer, but instead of trying to understand the `JOIN` syntax, you just write out all the logic and SQL is smart enough to make it work - this is often called the "new" or "ISO" inner join syntax, if you want to google for more info) (although it is possible, i suppose, that this newer syntax isn't supported by the database you are using).

Comment: Hello again. Thanks for the answer. It looks like the query is working, though its taking very long. Is that because we are searching 3 tables? Searching since ~10 minutes and no result yet.

Comment: speed depends on the system.  there's not much you can do if that's what you want.  BUT i am worried even when it finishes you will not have all the info you need.  you will only see what is in the `SELECT` - do you not need more info like the patent number or similar?  also, if you already have an example that you know is correct, an appln_id, for example, you could add `AND tls201_appln.appln_id = 1234` or whatever to check it is working more quickly.

Comment: What I need is just a list of joint patents. One column with all the applicants: Applicants (for. e.g. Samsung, IBM, Apple) and another row with number of applicants (here 3 for e.g.). That kind of data is what I am searching for. I thought my query will be delivering that kind of data, aint it?

Comment: I entirely disagree with this thesis. The use of explicit JOIN syntax is much easier to understand than implicit (comma-join) syntax - especially where multiple tables are involved.

Comment: Oh. I think the problem is, that I forget to define the time span for the search. That is probably why the query is taking so much time!?

Comment: reducing the time range will make things faster.  you want to add the statements as extra `AND` conditions with `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

> For my thesis I need to do a SQL query answering the question: "Give me all patents of a company X where there is more than one applicant (other company) in a specific time span".

Let me rephrase that for you :

```
SELECT * FROM patents p         -- : "Give me all patents 
WHERE p.company = 'X'           -- of a company X 
AND EXISTS (                    -- where there is 
        SELECT *
        FROM applicants x1
        WHERE x1.patent_id = p.patent_id
        AND x1.company <> 'X'   -- another company:: exclude ourselves
        AND x1.application_date >= $begin_date -- in a specific time span
        AND x1.application_date < $end_date
                -- more than one applicant (other company) 
                -- To avoid aggregation: Just repeat the same subquery
        AND EXISTS (                    -- where there is 
                SELECT *
                FROM applicants x2
                WHERE x2.patent_id = p.patent_id
                AND x2.company <> 'X'           -- another company:: exclude ourselves
                AND x2.company <> x1.company -- :: exclude other other company, too
                AND x2.application_date >= $begin_date -- in a specific time span
                AND x2.application_date < $end_date
                )
        )
        ;
```

[Note: Since the OP did not give any table definitions, I had to invent these]

This is *not* the perfect query, but it does express your intentions. Given sane keys/indexes it will perform reasonably, too.